# Configure MX and postfix

Tags: postfix-mta

I have two domains, dom1.com and dom2.com; dom1.com has IP1; the email for dom1.com are handled by google.

I need to create an email, xxx@dom2.com and redirect all emails to an email account of dom1.com ( example: yyy@dom1.com )

I 'd like to use postfix, installed on dom1.com server.

I set the MX record for dom2.com in this way:

```
     MX mail.dom2.com 
mail A  IP1
```

so mail.dom2.com should point to IP1.

To configure postfix on dom1.com server, I did as follow:

```
myhostname = dom1.com
mydestination = dom1.com, dom2.com


virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

in virtual_domains:

```
dom1.com     #domain
dom2.com     #domain
```

in virtual:

```
xxx@dom2.com yyy@dom1.com
```

than I did postmap for both files and I reload postfix ... but sending email to xxx@dom2.com , I don't reveice emails on yyy@dom1.com

Where is the error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Option what you want to use is: **Catch-all**

This Tutorial will help you to setup catch-all email address with postfix.

**Step 1. Configure Catch-All Account**

Edit /etc/postfix/virtual and configure your catch-all address like below.

```
# nano /etc/postfix/virtual
@example.com myuser
```

If you want to add exception’s in catch-all and do not want to catch-all specific accounts, Add them also in /etc/postfix/virtual file. Below configuration will send all emails to user “myuser” except emails of info@example.com and support@example.com.

```
@example.com myuser
info@example.com  info
support@example.com support
```

Save /etc/postfix/virtual file and execute following command.

```
# postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
```

**2. Update Postfix Configuration File**

Edit Postfix configuration file /etc/postfix/main.cf and add following line at end of file.

```
# nano /etc/postfix/main.cf

virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

**3. Reload Postfix Server**

After changing we need to reload server to activate newly settings addedUse following command to reload postfix configuration .

```
# service postfix reload
```